# how do i store the result of ICMP Reply Packet into variable for further use?

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I am new to python. As a beginner i am facing a problem that how to store the result of ICMP reply in to variable so that it can be further used in the script in python ? i am using scapy tool along with python for packet creation.
My script is-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

mac=”3c:97:0e:57:00:f1”

def build_req():

    For v in range(2, 4094):
        Pkt = sendp(Ether(src=”ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff”)/Dot1Q(vlan=v)/ARP(hwsrc=mac, psrc=”192.168.1.108”,pdst=”192.168.1.107”)/ICMP()/Padding(load=”x”*10),iface=”enp0s25”)
        If response is None:
            Print “vlan id is not found”
        Else:
            Print “vlan id found’  
            Sys.exit(1)
Return pkt
```

{ I want to store the icmp response coming from vlan id in a variable and use that response to send the packet }

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending packets, but not trying to get the response. Scapy documentation tells you how to do so:
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I can use sr() here instead of sendp(). can i use IP instead of ARP ?. and how i will store and print the response received from the packets?